# wrong version of ruby recognized on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, version-control, installation, version

I have an different version of ruby recognized by my windows10 cmd, even after I've uninstalled that version, and now it's preventing me from running bundle  update or bundle install.

```
C:\Users\marti\Documents\projects\discogsTagger\heroku\test2\jruby-getting-started>bundle install
Your Ruby version is 2.3.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.1
```

But if I run ruby -v, it says I have the correct version installed.

```
C:\Users\marti\Documents\projects\discogsTagger\heroku\test2\jruby-getting-started>ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x64-mingw32]
```

I'm trying to host a rubyonrails app with heroku, and need to be running 2.3.1, which is what I have installed, but cmd still thinks I'm using 2.3.3, which I've uninstalled. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Install the latest version of rails using the [install rails website](http://installrails.com/).

Then you want to type:

```
$rvm use ruby-2.3.1
```

This will force your system to use that specific version of ruby. If rails throws some errors, try this:

```
$gem update rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

**side note** I know your question is about ruby, but the rails installer should handle ruby too, and I see that your question is still externally in regards to rails.

Comment: @Martin No problem. I've added a small step just in case.

Comment: does railsinstaller automatically download rvm ?  win10 command prompt says command not found

Comment: Yes it does. The rails installer downloads and installs the "ruby version manager". For your future reference, anytime you try a command in cmd and it says "command not found" or something like that, it is because you are not in the directory where the executable is located. Browse to the directory where rvm is installed and try the commands there. Alternatively, you could add the rvm directory to your system path to be able to run it from any directory.

Also, runnig cmd "with ruby-on-rails" may allow you to run rvm commands from anywhere. Not positive though.